# Matrix with eigenvalue that should equal 1.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the matrix:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}4 & -2 & 3\\0 & -1 & 3\\-1 & 2 & -2 \end{bmatrix}$$

and I need to find out if $\lambda = 1$ is an eigenvalue. So I solved the equation $det(A - \lambda I)$ to find the answer, and I get $$-\lambda^3 + \lambda^2 + 19\lambda -7$$ which doesn't have $\lambda = 1$ as a solution. But I know that $\lambda = 1$ should be a solution, so now I'm stuck at figuring out why the correct answer doesn't correspond to my findings?

Comment: How do you know that $\lambda=1$ is an eigenvalue?

Comment: It appears that you computed the determinant incorrectly. Try again.

Comment: An eigenvector is  $\vec{x}=[0,3,2]^t$

Answer (score 2):

$$A-I=\begin{bmatrix} 3 & -2 & 3\\
0 & -2 & 3\\
-1 & 2 & -3
\end{bmatrix}$$

And you can see the two last columns are proportionate so the matrix is not invertible and $\lambda=1$ is an eigenvalue

My computation of $\det(A-\lambda I)=-\lambda^3+\lambda^2+13\lambda-13$

Comment: Beat me by a few seconds :)

Answer (score 0):

If $\lambda=1$ is an eigenvalue, then there is a vector $r$ such that $Ar=r$

Let $r=xi+yj+zk$

$Ar=r$ would mean that

$3x-2y+3z=x$ or $2x-2y+3z=0$

$-y+3z=y$ or $3z=2y$

$-x+2y-2z=z$ or $-x+2y-3z=0$

Are these equations consistent?